# Convert PDF returned in response to base64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

I’m trying to show a PDF in an iframe using PDF.js (this is not a PDF.js specific question. I’m just giving the context). The PDF is retrieved by calling a REST web service. I need to pass the PDF to PDF.js as a base64 encoded string.

I have tried several conversions (see example below), but none of them result in a working base64 string that can be displayed.
I assume my problem has to do with the file being streamed, but I don’t know how to deal with this in the right way.
The summary of the response below shows that the response contains several streams.

To confirm that the rest of the code works correctly, I have tried setting var pdfData to a base64 string of the pdf, generated using https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64 and it works fine. It displays my pdf correctly.
It starts like this:
JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSA+PgpzdHJlYW0KeAF9jj0LwjAQhn..

Can anyone please offer some advise on how to get a working base64 encoded string from the response I get from my REST web service?

Summary of that is written to console for response (cut out some data to show the streams):

```
%PDF-1.3
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x}�=�0�w��w2�&i��Uqq+ܦN�C���9����(ϣ%���ƘZ�pu���-�������-��$i��D|>L����BzJG?�����Fs���[M��ij?���<�+�e�հ���ڇ   �Z%�����
z)/�
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
[removed content]
<< /Length 11 0 R /N 3 /Alternate /DeviceRGB /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x��wTS��Ͻ7��" %�z     �;HQ�I�P��&vDF)VdT�G�"cE��b�  �P��QDE�݌k �5�ޚ��Y�����g�}׺
[removed content]
<< /Size 24 /Root 12 0 R /Info 1 0 R /ID [ <73b9fa8794abac5a7f7e740da4a1ae7a>
<73b9fa8794abac5a7f7e740da4a1ae7a> ] >>
startxref
13328
%%EOF
```

Summary of code:

```
<script>
  var pdfData = '';

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.ajax('myurl',
      {
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          // Set the OAuth header from the session ID
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer removed');
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("response: " + response);

          var pdfData = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response)));
          //Result (first line only): JVBERi0xLjMKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/

          //var pdfData = btoa(unescape(response));
          //Result: results in Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': 
          //        The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

          //var pdfData = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response)));
          //Result (first line only): JVBERi0xLjMKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQo0ID


          //var pdfData = Base64.btoa(response);
          //Result: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': 
          //        The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

          //var pdfData = Base64.encode(response);
          //Result (first line only): JVBERi0xLjMKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQo0ID



        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(jqXHR.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
      }
    );
  });

  //more code to pass pdfData to pdf viewer
</script>
```

Comment: this link may be useful to you: https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js

Comment: Did you try complete and not success?

Comment: @YunusSaha Base64. js says it provides polyfill for browsers which don't provide window.btoa and window.atob. I have access to btoa and atob. I tried those and other options and I don't think that is where my issue is. I suspect that input I'm providing the function is not correct.

Comment: @KevinBrown Not sure what you mean? I haven't got a solution to this issue yet.

Comment: You are using ajax success for your process. Possibly the stream is still downloading. Use complete instead.

Comment: I tried complete instead of success, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and find this solution

You need setConfig for your client and specify decoder. For my promlem it was ISO_8859_1

`new RequestSpecBuilder().setConfig(config().decoderConfig(new DecoderConfig().defaultContentCharset(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))`